# Does Deleting a Branch Deletes It's Sub-branches?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-branch

I created a branch `feature` from branch `develop`, after working on the branch `feature`, the whole requirement changed, now I need to reset my whole work on this feature but I need to keep a backup.

So I created a branch `feature_backup` from `feature`, and I want to delete the `feature` branch and start all over again with the same branch name.

Does deleting the `feature` branch **(without merging it to the develop branch)** deletes it's sub-branch `feature_backup` ?

Comment: A branch is really just a *label* pointing to a commit, so no.

Comment: There is no such thing as *sub-branch* in git, even if the idea can be useful to explain or understand some workflows. All branches are equal and independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, deleting `feature` branch does not touch `feature_backup` branch in any way.

Comment: @MhmdRizk Risk of this happening is zero. Go for it.